# How can i fix error "Unable to export or encrypt the private key tag = -96" while generating pepk private key (Android)

Tags: android, private-key, google-developers-console

Hello I have problem while I trying to generate priva key for google console to upload android application file. The Error is:

```
Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
        at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:239)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:352)
        at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.readPublicKey(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:309)
        at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.encryptPrivateKeyWithCkmRsaAesKeyWrapEncryption(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:283)
        at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:213)
        at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:165)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:396)
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:401)
        at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:122)
        at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:330)
        at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:235)
```

STEPS:

1.
keytool -genkey -v -keystore myfile.keystore -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

2.
keytool -export -rfc -alias myalias -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore myfile.keystore

3.
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=myfile.keystore --alias=myalias --output=encrypted_private_key --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=upload_certificate.pem

Above error shown after 3th command line.

or Error with a jks from Android Studio, error tag = 2

```
Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 2)
        at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:239)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:352)
        at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.readPublicKey(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:309)
        at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.encryptPrivateKeyWithCkmRsaAesKeyWrapEncryption(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:283)
        at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:213)
        at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:165)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 2)
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:396)
        at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:401)
        at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:122)
        at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:330)
        at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:235)
```